# How does google answers use .py files?

Tags: python

How does google manage to have actual .py scripts on its webpage (https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10313)? It seems that the parameters 'en' and '10313' are passed to the answer.py script. I have seen a website that does the following: answer.php?hl=en&answer=10313, but how would you use a python script in such a way?

Comment: You can run Python scripts from webservers: http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using an application server or a webserver configured to run Python scripts? There are [many options to run Python](http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html) serving web requests.

Note that extensions don't mean anything anymore these days; the `.py` extension could even be an internal joke on us all where the pages are really served by Haskell..